# ConnectionResetError when trying to send PUT request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to upload a file using a PUT REST Api, but I get a `ConnectionResetError`. I've tried using `urllib.request.Request()` with `urllib.request.urlopen()`, as well as `requests.put()`.

It works correctly when I'm using cURL:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:5000/root.bar/test/1.0/jre -H 'Content-Type: application/java-archive' -H 'Content-Name: bfg-1.12.16.jar' -H 'Authorization: Basic cm9vdDphbHBpbmU=' -d @C:/Users/niklas/Desktop/bfg-1.12.16.jar
```

The important portion of the code:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': args.mime, 'Content-Name': args.name}
if args.auth:
  headers['Authorization'] = build_basicauth(username, password)
url = args.apiurl.rstrip('/') + '/{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(*parts)
if not urllib.parse.urlparse(url).scheme:
  url = 'https://' + url

if args.test:
  command = ['curl', '-X', 'PUT', url]
  for key, value in headers.items():
    command += ['-H', '{}: {}'.format(key, value)]
  command += ['-d', '@' + args.file.name]
  print('$', ' '.join(map(shlex.quote, command)))
  return 0

response = requests.put(url, data=args.file, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

**What am I missing that cURL is doing?**

(PS: I've also tried sending `bytes` instead of a file-like object using `requests.put()` by passing `data=args.file.read()` instead)

---

The full traceback:

```
$ python -m fatartifacts.web.cli http://localhost:5000 root.bar:test:1.0:jre ~/Desktop/bfg-1.12.16.jar  -m application/java-archive -u root:alpine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\http\client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\repos\fatartifacts\fatartifacts\web\cli.py", line 106, in <module>
    main_and_exit()
  File "C:\Users\niklas\repos\fatartifacts\fatartifacts\web\cli.py", line 102, in main_and_exit
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\niklas\repos\fatartifacts\fatartifacts\web\cli.py", line 97, in main
    response = requests.put(url, data=args.file, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 126, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\.virtualenvs\fatartifacts-LoWBpE4v\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

---

The REST API is implemented with `flask` and `flask-restful`. This exception seems to happen when

- issuing the request using Python (`urllib.request`, `requests`)
- the API returns a non-200 status code using `flask.abort()`

Comment: If you do `print(url)`, what exactly will URL look like?

Comment: @Torxed Exactly what you see in the CURL request (as it was generated using the code you see above). If you were opting to find out if it is a `bytes` or `str` object, then I can tell you that it is a `str`. :)

Comment: That's strange Niklas, considering the output in the CURL request is HTTPS, and the code says `http://`. You're also invoking `shlex.quote` which might do magic for you, enabling CURL to work but the socket in request not to. That's why I asked if you could do a print just before the request statement.

Comment: @Torxed Where do you see HTTPS? The CURL command in the question contains an HTTP URL, and so does the `python -m fatartifacts.web.cli` invokation. `print(url)` before the request gives `http://localhost:5000/root.bar/test/1.0/jre`. -- The `https://` is only added when the URL does not already have a scheme.

Comment: @Torxed Ah, I want to add that the request does reach the REST API, and I can do a request successfully when it would return status `200`. Here however it would return status `400`.  The REST API is implemented in Flask. I'll update the question with that info as well.

Comment: Are you in a docker (or similar) container?

Comment: @Torxed No, I'm not. I just rebuilt the REST API using plain Flask and not Flask-Restful, and I no longer get the ConnectionResetError. So it appears that it is an issue with Flask-Restful, or my usage of it. One thing is still odd, and that is that the Request I issue from Python code is not handled until I issue another request (eg. via the Browser). But that surely is another issue.

Comment: @Torxed Wait, maybe I tested wrong. I **still do get the ConnectionResetError**, even without using Flask-Restful.

Comment: @Torxed Figured out the issue, see answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the Flask REST API didn't consume all the content that was being sent with the request. The Flask application called `abort(403)` before the `flask.request.stream` was read.

Since I don't want to read all the data when the request is being rejected anyway, I found out that calling `request.environ['wsgi.input'].close()` closes the stream without reading it's content first, and this avoids the `ConnectionResetError` on the client-side.

```
def close_input_stream(func):
  @functools.wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*a, **kw):
    try:
      return func(*a, **kw)
    finally:
      fp = request.environ.get('wsgi.input')
      if fp:
        fp.close()
  return wrapper
```